# Date conversion from regexp output data -- ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp, date-conversion

I am trying to convert a value to the normal date format. But i am receiving the error ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0   . I have researched the answers for a similar question in this website but that doesn't address my issue.

```
-- How the data looks like 
select REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(data_detail, '([^|]*)([$|]|$)', 1, 5), '|', '') from land.LAND_DATA;
```

Output

2017-11-16T04:45:05.000Z

2017-11-16T04:46:04.000Z

When i am trying to convert the above mentioned output in to an appropriate date format i am receiving the error. What mistake am i doing here

```
select
TO_DATE(
TO_CHAR(
TO_TIMESTAMP(
     REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(data_detail, '([^|]*)([$|]|$)', 1, 5), '|', ''), 
'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
        'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
from land.LAND_DATA;
```

Answer (score 0):

These results are input data for the [TO_TIMESTAMP function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm):

```
2017-11-16T04:45:05.000Z
2017-11-16T04:46:04.000Z
```

A year comes first, then a month and a day, and a time follows, which has milliseconds at the very end (after the comma).

---

This is a snippet from your code:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP( ....... , 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )
```

the second parameter is [a date format model](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924), these letters have the following meaning (in order):

- `MM` - Month (01-12; January = 01).
- `/` - separator
- `DD` - Day of month (1-31)
- `/` - separator
- `YYYY` - 4-digit year; S prefixes BC dates with a minus sign.
- - separator (space)
- `HH24` - Hour of day (0-23).
- `:` - separator
- `MI` - Minute (0-59).
- `:` - separator
- `SS` - Second (0-59).

---

The above format models doesn't match a format of input data, because a month comes first in this format, but your data starts with a year !!!
**Use the following format instead**:

```
'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff"Z"'
```

---

You can test whether a format is fine or gives an error using a simple query like this:

```
select 
    to_timestamp( '2017-11-16T04:45:05.000Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff"Z"')
from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-11-16T04:4
-----------------------------
2017/11/16 04:45:05.000000000
```